# Como ejecutar un archivo PHP al iniciar Fedora 25

Tags: php, linux, consola, fedora

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un *PHP* automaticamente al iniciar *Fedora 25 Desktop*?

Ocupo ejecutar:

```
php /var/www/asterisk-connector.php
```

Siempre que inicie *Fedora 25* y no se detenga su ejecución, este archivo se mantiene siempre conectado con mi conmutador *Asterisk* esperando eventos, la idea es que si se va la luz en cuanto regrese arranque el servidor y se ejecute el script *PHP* ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo paso por paso?

Comment: inserta ese comando en el archivo /etc/rc.local antes de la ultima linea.

Answer (score 0):

Cron o demonio...

Son tareas programadas que están en constante ejecución dependiendo su configuración.

Primero revisa si ya tienes sistema de cron instalado y corriendo

```
/sbin/service crond status
```

Si no tienes el servicio instalalo con el siguiente comando.

```
rpm -q vixie-cron
```

Para la configuracion el archivo de configuración principal de cron, **/etc/crontab**, contiene las siguientes líneas:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root HOME=/
# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Las primeras cuatro líneas son variables que se utilizan para configurar el entorno en el que se ejecutan las tareas cron. La variable **SHELL** de sistema que le dice al entorno de shell a utilizar (en este ejemplo, el shell bash), mientras que la variable **PATH** define la ruta usada para ejecutar comandos. La salida de las tareas cron se enviará por correo electrónico el nombre de usuario definido con la variable **MAILTO**. Si la variable **MAILTO** se define como una cadena vacía ( MAILTO=""), el correo electrónico no se envía. La variable **HOME** puede ser utilizado para establecer el directorio principal de utilizar al ejecutar los comandos o secuencias de comandos.

Cada línea del archivo **/etc/crontab**  representa una tarea y tiene el siguiente formato:

```
minute   hour   day   month   dayofweek   command
```

Aquí puedes configurar un archivo **.sh** y dentro poder estar ejecutando una serie de comandos entre ellos la llamada a el script de **PHP** y establecer fechas y tiempo de ejecución.

Para iniciar el CRON **/sbin/service crond start** y para detenerlos **/sbin/service crond stop**